# Outlook Add in sends email to draft

Tags: outlook-addin, add-in, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Outlook Add in with the OnSend feature. Some testers reported to me that sometimes the Add in prevents their mail from being sent and saves the email to draft. The following pop up shows when this happens:

[image]

Most of the times it works without any problem, so code wise this is not a problem, but all of the testers that reported this bug have in common that they are using Windows Outlook on Desktop. Are there any known issues regarding this that might cause it? Is there any way of debugging to see what is happening and why it is happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have reached the timeout for the [On-send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) or just an exception was thrown in the event handler, or if `event.completed()` hasn't been called before then. Make sure the `event.completed()` call is made when you are done.

The best what you can do for desktop editions of Outlook is to log your actions.

Here is what MS states for such dialogs:

> These errors are valid, and aren't able to be avoided. If your add-in hasn't finished, and the user closes the item, then they are warned the email hasn't actually been sent yet. Please be sure that your add-in calls event.completed() to notify Outlook your add-in action has completed.

Comment: As well as the answer above, this behavior can happen if the user navigates away from the message while the message in running (ex: this can happen on an inline reply).